# pure css resizable grid

Tags: html, css

Requirements:

- grid of three divs:

  ```
   ------------
   |one | two |
   ------------
   |  three   |
   ------------
  ```
- border between one and two and between three and one/two should be resizable in such a way, that all three together always fill 100% width and height and there is at no time a gap between any of the divs
- overflow should be prevented

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "three three";
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}


.one {
    grid-area: one;
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.two {
    grid-area: two;
    border: 3px dotted red;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.three {
    grid-area: three;
    border: 3px dotted black;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? At first glance it looks as though the code is ok.

Comment: I think the question is how to keep the divs working together when the `resize` handles are being used.

Comment: right. Like I said: "... should be resizable in such a way, that all three together always fill 100% width and height and there is at no time a gap between any of the divs ..."

Comment: So what is to happen when one of the top items gets made taller/wider/shorter/narrower? I'm not clear which dimensions of which item are to 'win' and force the other item to alter to accommodate the change.

Comment: When I drag the blue one to the left, the red one gets dragged along just to the middle and not further. When I drag the blue one outside further to the right then the container, the red one disappears outside the visible frame. When I drag the blue one to the bottom, I can do so also further than the container frame. I want all this not to happen

Comment: Yes, but what DO you want to happen? Perhaps start by describing exactly what should happen to each of the 3 elements when the first one is dragged diagonally to the left and up - including what that restriction on height is to mean.

Comment: I thought that my requirements to the grid would be already sufficiently pointed out but I try to be more exact. When dragging any of the three borders, separating the divs one, two and three, I would want the others to fill the else wise empty gap in such a way that all three together at all times occupy the surrounding container div and at the same time do not lead to enlarge the container or that one, two or three would get pushed outside of it.