# nested Split.js in dash using dash-split not possible (?)

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I've been trying for a while to create a [dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) app divided into three main parts like so:
[image]

1. My first approach was with only [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77115138/pure-css-resizable-grid?noredirect=1#comment135955095_77115138).
   I could not make it work because it overflows the container div, while the inner ones do not grow/shrink the same way as their neighbors do.
2. So I tried to use [dash-draggable](https://dash-draggable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However it suffers from a ... let's say very limited documentation and is ultimately not made for my requirements, I think.
3. The approach I'm currently working on is to use [dash-split](https://pypi.org/project/dash-split/). It works well for simple splits but not for nested ones like I intend to do.

```
import dash
from dash_split import Split
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

style = {
    "height": "50vh",
    "display": "flex",
    "justifyContent": "center",
    "alignItems": "center"
}

app.layout = html.Div([
    Split(
        id='split-vertical', 
        direction='vertical', 
        children=[
                Split(
                    id='split',
                    children=[
                        html.Div(id='2', children="main grapg", style=style),
                        html.Div(id='3', children="settings", style=style),
                    ]),
            html.Div(id='1', children="some grid", style=style),
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Anyone with an idea (or a completely different approach)?
I also tried to implement [Split.js](https://split.js.org/) manually into dash which faced the same problems.